# Integration of Hypergeometric Function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

`E^(2 ArcSinh[a z]) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 4 + Sqrt[2], -E^(2 ArcSinh[a z])]`
I want to integrate wrt z. Here it is not evaluating anything. Can you solve it?

Comment: Why do you expect that there is a closed form solution? Not all integrals can be expressed in closed form.

Comment: Then how can it be solved?

Comment: Integrated through numerical means or other approximating techniques.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you just try to integrate it using `Integrate`?

Answer (score 11):

This is more of a math question than a Mathematica question.

First, some simplifications. Define $x=a z$ and note that

$$
e^{2 \sinh^{-1} x} = 1 + 2 x^2 + 2 x \sqrt{1 + x^2}
$$

In Mathematica,

```
E^(2 ArcSinh[x]) // ExpToTrig // TrigExpand
(*    1 + 2 x^2 + 2 x Sqrt[1 + x^2]    *)
```

The integral in question is therefore

$$
J=\int e^{2 \sinh^{-1}(a z)} \,_2F_1\left(1,3+\sqrt{2};4+\sqrt{2};-e^{2 \sinh^{-1}(a z)}\right)dz\\
= \frac{1}{a} \int e^{2 \sinh^{-1}x} \,_2F_1\left(1,3+\sqrt{2};4+\sqrt{2};-e^{2 \sinh^{-1}x}\right)dx\\
= \frac{1}{a} \int (1 + 2 x^2 + 2 x \sqrt{1 + x^2}) \,_2F_1\left(1,3+\sqrt{2};4+\sqrt{2};-1 - 2 x^2 - 2 x \sqrt{1 + x^2})\right)dx
$$

Next, we substitute $x=-\frac{1+y}{2\sqrt{-y}}$ with $y<0$:

$$
J= \frac{1}{a} \int \frac{y-1}{4\sqrt{-y}}\,_2F_1\left(1,3+\sqrt{2};4+\sqrt{2};y\right)dy
$$
Mathematica knows how to integrate this:

```
Integrate[(y-1)*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3+Sqrt[2], 4+Sqrt[2], y]/(4*Sqrt[-y]), y] // FullSimplify

(*    (1/((46 + 32 Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-y]))(-2 (19 + 11 Sqrt[2]) y +
      4 (3 + Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[y] ArcTanh[Sqrt[y]] +
      y (3 + 2 Sqrt[2] - (5 + 2 Sqrt[2]) y) *
      Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 4 + Sqrt[2], y])    *)
```

Or, more automatically,

```
f[x_] = E^(2 ArcSinh[x]) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 4 + Sqrt[2], -E^(2 ArcSinh[x])];

Assuming[y < 0,
  IntegrateChangeVariables[Integrate[f[x], x], y,
  x == -(y+1)/(2*Sqrt[-y])] // FullSimplify // Activate // FullSimplify]
(*    (-2 (19 + 11 Sqrt[2]) y + 4 (3 + Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[y] ArcTanh[Sqrt[y]] +
      y (3 + 2 Sqrt[2] - (5 + 2 Sqrt[2]) y) *
      Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 4 + Sqrt[2], y])/((46 + 32 Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-y])    *)
```

Let's check by differentiation:

```
f[x_] = E^(2 ArcSinh[x]) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 4 + Sqrt[2], -E^(2 ArcSinh[x])];
G[y_] = 1/((46 + 32 Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-y]) (-2 (19 + 11 Sqrt[2]) y +
        4 (3 + Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[y] ArcTanh[Sqrt[y]] +
        y (3 + 2 Sqrt[2] -
        (5 + 2 Sqrt[2]) y) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 4 + Sqrt[2], y]);
F[x_] = G[-1 - 2 x^2 - 2 x Sqrt[1 + x^2]];

Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, F'[x] == f[x] // FullSimplify]
(*    True    *)
```

Final check by numerical integration:

```
With[{x1 = 0.3, x2 = 0.9},
  {NIntegrate[f[x], {x, x1, x2}],
   F[x2] - F[x1]}]
(*    {0.535963, 0.535963 + 0. I}    *)
```

You'll still have to prefix the factor $\frac{1}{a}$ that I left out at the end.

After further manual simplification:

```
F[x_] = ((38 + 22 Sqrt[2]) E^ArcSinh[x] - 4 (3 + Sqrt[2]) ArcTan[E^ArcSinh[x]] -
        E^ArcSinh[x] (3 + 2 Sqrt[2] + (5 + 2 Sqrt[2]) E^(2 ArcSinh[x])) *
        Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 4 + Sqrt[2], -E^(2 ArcSinh[x])])/(46 + 32 Sqrt[2]);

F'[x] == f[x] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting `a=1` and using `NIntegrate` in the interval -10 to 10, you get `0+12.6451 i` for example

```
NIntegrate[
 E^(2 ArcSinh[1 z]) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 
   4 + Sqrt[2], -E^(2 ArcSinh[1 z])] I, {z, -10, 10}]
```

You can also plot the Real and Imaginary parts of your function to see what the function looks like as well (the real part turns out to be zero):

```
Plot[Im[E^(2 ArcSinh[1 z]) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 + Sqrt[2], 
    4 + Sqrt[2], -E^(2 ArcSinh[1 z])] I], {z, -10, 10}]
```

[image]